# PostgreSQL trigger to allow update of only one specific column

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Is it possible to create such trigger function, without specifying by name the other columns that shouldn't be affected?

Example:

```
Create table test(id integer, name text, amount numeric);
```

I'd like to prevent updates of any columns other than `amount`, but to avoid specifying by name columns `id` and `name` like this

```
IF NEW.id <> OLD.id or NEW.name <> OLD.name THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'UPDATE DISALLOWED'; END IF;
```

I would like to apply this trigger to multiple tables, that's why I don't want to specify the other columns.

Comment: You could use [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-grant.html)  at the column level: `GRANT UPDATE(colname) ON TABLE tablename TO somerole`.

Comment: Is it possible to revoke updates from postgres role? Or do it using row level security?

Answer (score 1):

You could update and return the `OLD` record from the trigger function.

```
BEGIN
    OLD.amount := NEW.amount;
    RETURN OLD;
END;
```

To raise an exception if an attempt has been made to update other columns, you could check if the records are distinct from each other.

```
BEGIN
    OLD.amount := NEW.amount;

    IF (NEW IS DISTINCT FROM OLD) THEN
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'UPDATE of columns other than "amount" is forbidden';
    END IF;

    RETURN OLD;
END;
```